# Error: "Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access..."

Tags: firebase-storage

I'm trying to write a Firebase Cloud Function to get an audio file from an API and save it to Firebase Storage. I'm getting this error:

```
Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'Audio/English/United_States-OED-0/winter.mp3'. (storage/unauthorized)
```

I'm getting the same error using the emulator and the cloud. No file is written in Storage. The log `Uploaded a string!'` doesn't appear.

I have a Firebase IAM service account. I know how to import it into a CommonJS module (`require`) but my functions are in an ES module (`import`). How do I import my service account? This didn't work because `assert` only works in Node 17, when Firebase Functions uses Node 16.

```
import serviceAccount from "./my-awesome-project-firebase-adminsdk-12345.json" assert { type: "json" };
```

Here's my cloud function:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { getStorage, ref, uploadString, connectStorageEmulator } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ...,
    authDomain: ...,
    databaseURL: ...,
    projectId: ...,
    storageBucket: "my-awesome-project.appspot.com",
    appId: "..."
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

import got from 'got';

export const Oxford_T2S = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/English/OED_T2S_Request').onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const storage = getStorage(app);
  connectStorageEmulator(storage, "localhost", 9199); // comment out to use cloud
  const audioEnglishOEDWinterRef = ref(storage, 'Audio/English/United_States-OED-0/winter.mp3');

  async function getOED() {
    try {
      let file = await got('https://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/winter__us_2.mp3');
      uploadString(audioEnglishOEDWinterRef, file).then((snapshot) => {
          console.log('Uploaded a string!');
      });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
  }

  return getOED()
});
```

Here are my cloud rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {   
    // anything using request.auth.token relies on the userLogin cloud function.
    
    match /Audio/{shortLangA}/{file=**} {
        // allow writing of audio files if the user is trusted or a teacher of the language, apply recursively
        allow write: if (request.auth.token.trusted || shortLangA in request.auth.token.teaches);
    }
    
     match /Users/{file=**} {
        // allow writing of pronunciation tests
        // this rule is insecure
      // this rule needs to be improved by allowing users to only write to their own folders
      allow read, write: if true;
    }

    match /{allPaths=**} {
      // Only authenticated users can read from the bucket
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried spinning up my Angular project and logging in but that didn't help.

Here are my emulator rules. These are the default rules created by `firebase init functions`:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

I changed `false` to `true` but that didn't help.

Documentation on `got` is [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/main/documentation/quick-start.md). That line isn't throwing errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748738/swift-3-record-audio-and-upload-to-firebase-storage-and-play-back This is how I uploaded audio file to Firebase Storage in iOS, the logic should be similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Cloud Storage error messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors) documentation says

```
storage/unauthorized
User is not authorized to perform the desired action, check your security rules to ensure they are correct.
```

Looking at the emulator's default `storage.rules`, nothing can read or write. Gee, thanks for protecting my emulator from Russian hackers. The default should be

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write
    }
  }
}
```

Even with the new rules the emulator seems to be finicky. Sometimes a file writes, most of the time nothing writes to Storage.

My Cloud Storage rules, particularly `request.auth.token.trusted`, are set up for calls from my Angular app. If the call isn't coming from a logged in user on the app then the request is stopped. I.e., testing the Cloud Function in the Firebase Console won't write to Storage.